# Adding a listener to Seekbar

Tags: android, listener, seekbar

I am trying to use a Seekbar in android studio so that the user can input a certain value 1-100. However, I can't figure out how to add a listener to the Seekbar.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can set a listener on seekbar for seekbar position change

```
 seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);  
 seekBar1.setMax(1000);
 seekBar1.setProgress(50);
```

sample code

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener{  
    SeekBar seekBar1;  
    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

        seekBar1=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);  
        seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); 
        seekBar1.setMax(1000); 
    }  
    @Override  
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,  
            boolean fromUser) {  
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"seekbar progress: "+progress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    }  
    @Override  
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {  
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"seekbar touch started!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    }  
    @Override  
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {  
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"seekbar touch stopped!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to implement an interface, use this

```
sk.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {       

@Override       
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {      
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}       

@Override       
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {     
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}       

@Override       
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {     
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      


    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(progress),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```